# Virtuemart - add to cart, without prices

Tags: php, joomla, shopping-cart, virtuemart

I'm trying to change some of the Virtuemart code, so I can show items and add them to cart, but without prices.  The whole checkout process should be the same, but the purchase order has to be sent without prices(more like a 'quote').

It is a requirement of a project I'm working on. I've already seen that the action of showing prices is directly attached to the 'add to cart' functionality, so If anyone can suggest some hint about how to separate these 2 functionalities it will be a great help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just remove the HTML/PHP that displays the price in the basket, checkout page and in the order email?

Comment: I've been trying to do that so far, but I've had quite a time searching for the php files that handle the add to cart functionality

Comment: Good Idea, I'm on it right now.  I've edited the order email, but didn't knew about the basket.php files.  Working on it!

Comment: by the way, what does the tpl extension means? example: _confirmation_email.**tpl**.php_ @Martin

Comment: tpl means it is a template file. it's the one used to creat the related email/page.

Comment: Brent is right about that. Most of the files you need to look at are in components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates. However with regards to the basket you will need to look into the admin section at basket.php and basket_ro.php

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you can use CSS to hide the price fields so you don't have to touch any of the code or create new theme files. It should be as easy as adding this to your stylesheet -

```
span.productPrice{display:none;}
```

Comment: really??? And this will mantain the 'add to cart' functionality??? Let me try that!

Comment: just tried it in the style.css file inside /theme ; it didn't hid the prices.

Comment: i'm using the default theme; did I searched in the wrong place?

Comment: Use Firebug, or Inspect Element in the newer browser versions to see what CSS rules are being applied to the prices.

Comment: I've tried this, but just can't find where to add this line in the layout.css file.  I checked the CSS rules that apply to the vmCartModule box in the web page, but they are only the ones for 'body' in the CSS.

Comment: You should be able to add it to the template css file, that is one of the last ones loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Worked.. you have to find the theme.css in components/com_virtuemart/themes/yourtheme

I just added the !important in the end and it worked..

span.productPrice{display:none; !important}

Of course that doesn't hide the price from the card.. but that is another thing to be solved